# Javascript regexp modifiers

Tags: javascript, regex

This code gets html data and should replace all javascript content

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function(data){
        data = data.replace(/<script.*?<\/sc/mg,'');
        alert(data);
    },
    dataType: 'html'
});
```

But there is stay javascript code in the `data`

```
.....</div><!-- end header -->
<div id="snapshot">
    <a href="?cat=<div style=&panel=center" id="leftNav" class="navlink"><i class="icon-previous icon-large white"></i></a>

    <a href="?cat=<div style=&panel=left" id="rightNav" class="navlink"><i class="icon-next icon-large white"></i></a>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').append('<div id="loaded_page"></div>');
    url = $('#leftNav').attr('href')
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(data){
            data = data.replace(/<script.*?<\/sc/mgi,'');
            alert(data);
        },
        dataType: 'html'
    });

    return;
</script>
    ....................
```

So I need result to be

```
.....</div><!-- end header -->
<div id="snapshot">
    <a href="?cat=<div style=&panel=center" id="leftNav" class="navlink"><i class="icon-previous icon-large white"></i></a>

    <a href="?cat=<div style=&panel=left" id="rightNav" class="navlink"><i class="icon-next icon-large white"></i></a>
```

all javascript should be cut. Regexp `data.replace(/<script.*?<\/sc/mg,'')` replaces things which are in a one line only

Comment: and what is the data format you need to regexp?

Comment: regexp doesn't work, it should replace <script.*?<\/sc with ''

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.* doesn't work in javascript over new lines. Instead use [\s\S]*

Here's the regex:

```
/<script[\s\S]*?</script>/i
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

```
var html = "<html><head><script src='http://jquery.js'></script>\n<script src='http://jquery.js'></script></head><body>I m legend</body></html>";
html.replace(/<script.*?<\/script>/gi,'');
```

This will return :

```
"<html><head>
</head><body>I m legend</body></html>"
```

Answer (score 0):

> [T]o match a pattern across multiple lines the character set [^] can be used (if you don't mean an old version of IE, of course), it will match any character including newlines.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

This means you should use the negative empty selection `[^]` instead of the dot `.` to match "all characters".